# Wix Run Custom Action When "Newer version is installed"

Tags: wix, custom-action

How can I setup custom action to run my app when installation finished with "newer version is already installed"?

What I want: If newer version is installed, just run it. Run application always except deleting.

My configuration:

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" Directory='INSTALLFOLDER' ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]\MyApp.exe"
              Return="asyncNoWait" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="LaunchApplication" After="InstallFinalize">NOT (REMOVE="ALL")</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Thanks

Comment: The message is generated when detection is evaluating. Your custom action will never run. Why you are trying to run some app if someone trying to install lower version of the installer?

Comment: I want to run the version that is already installed (newer)

Comment: Can you post your upgrade element? The message "newer version is already installed" appears when you are trying to install an older version. It's not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with logs: `app.msi /l*v log.txt`

Working configuration:

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" Directory='INSTALLFOLDER' ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]\MyApp.exe"
              Return="asyncNoWait" />
<CustomAction Id="SetLaunchApplicationPath" Property="LaunchApplicationPath" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\MyApp.exe">
</CustomAction>
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplicationOnDowngrade" ExeCommand="[SetLaunchApplicationPath]" Property="LaunchApplicationPath"
              Return="asyncNoWait" />

<InstallUISequence >
  <Custom Action="SetLaunchApplicationPath" After="FindRelatedProducts">WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED</Custom>
  <Custom Action="LaunchApplicationOnDowngrade" After="SetLaunchApplicationPath">LaunchApplicationPath</Custom>
</InstallUISequence>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="LaunchApplication" After="InstallFinalize" >NOT (REMOVE="ALL")</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Action LaunchApplication executes when install/update finished
Action LaunchApplicationOnDowngrade executes when install failed when newer version of product is found by FindRelatedProducts Action

I use `<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed."  />` to configure upgrade.